# Obtain Enigma key having a encrypted text and the plain text

Tags: known-plaintext-attack, enigma

I have an Enigma message and I know what the original message is (a repetition of the same letter). Is it possible obtain the enigma key? I only know what kind of Enigma machine is it, but I need to guess the config. parameters.

Comment: nobody can help me?

Comment: Of course you can get the key, they did it back in WWII and your phone probably has more computing power than all the bombes put together. But Cryptography.SE is not a decryption service. Please show what you've tried and what research you've done on how the Enigma was cracked. For example, you could work through [the Enigma cracking exercises at Virtual Bletchley Park](http://www.codesandciphers.co.uk/anoraks/scenios.htm).